# cleaner code suggestion to string manipulation

Tags: java

So I put a lot of thought into the logic of my if statement in line 6 of my code. But I was hoping to get some feedback from more experienced developers.. Do you guys think I just over complicated my code and if so, how would you have written this more concise?

[image]

Comment: check this out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm

Comment: Just a tip: please post the code, and not just an image of it. Having the actual text makes it easier to help (less of a big deal here since it's small, but having just an image is a headache for larger pieces of code), and also makes the text searchable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Over-complicating? Yes, you really are :-)

I would just be using the much simpler:

```
public String seeColor (String color) {
    if (color.startsWith("red")) return "red";
    if (color.startsWith("blue")) return "blue";
    return "";
}
```

The following complete program shows it in action:

```
public class Test
{
    public static String seeColor (String color) {
        if (color.startsWith("red")) return "red";
        if (color.startsWith("blue")) return "blue";
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testData = { "redxx", "xxred", "blueTimes", "NoColor",
            "red", "re", "blu", "blue", "a", "", "xyzred" };
        for (String s: testData)
            System.out.println("[" + s + "] -> [" + seeColor(s) + "]");
    }
}
```

The output of that program being, as expected:

```
[redxx] -> [red]
[xxred] -> []
[blueTimes] -> [blue]
[NoColor] -> []
[red] -> [red]
[re] -> []
[blu] -> []
[blue] -> [blue]
[a] -> []
[] -> []
[xyzred] -> []
```

---

If you want it easily expandable in future, you could opt for something like:

```
public static String seeColor (String color) {
    String[] allow = {"red", "blue"};
    for (String s: allow)
        if (color.startsWith(s))
            return s;
    return "";
}
```

Then, adding a color to the `allow` array is the only step you need to take to have it recognised.

Comment: Great explanation.. I did see the startsWith() naturally returns a boolean, I didn't realize you could still return a string from that, but it makes sense that you can, based on the result being true or false.. Also I think the last piece of code with the for each loop is genius for practicality in future use. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you'd be better off encapsulating your colour names in a stream so that it can be easily expanded rather than having to add new if branches:

```
return Stream.of("red", "blue", "green")
    .filter(colourName::startsWith).findAny().orElse("");
```

Note that this solution relies on Java 8 streams and method references.

Comment: Ooh, Java 8 has some nifty new features.

Comment: Love the solution but I don't quite get the syntax. The method has a return type of String, so I assume this works because you've made it an Array of, String[] acceptableColours. However, I want to better understand your .fliter() and what purpose the double :: provide. I'm looking through the java 8 Docs on those last 3 proceeding methods after .stream() but can't find them

Comment: .filter and .findAny are methods of Steam. .orElse is a method of Optional. For the :: syntax look at lamba expressions.

Comment: Java tutorial on method references: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: Good answer. I think it would be good to mention, that this solution uses lambda expressions and therefore is only applicable to java >= 8.

Comment: @brimborium Ok I've added that. Though it's been out for quite a while now - hopefully we can start assuming it in answers soon!

Comment: @sprinter Thanks for adding. It is always a good thing to mention compatibility versions, especially in Java where a lot of code is relying on old JREs (for example because they're running on old or limited machines that can not support newer versions of Java).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you might simplify it with something like

```
if (str != null) {
    if (str.equals("red")) return "red";
    else if (str.equals("blue")) return "blue";
}
return "";
```

or the slightly more complicated `switch`

```
if (str != null) {
    switch (str) {
    case "red":
        return "red";
    case "blue";
        return "blue";
    }
}
return "";
```

Testing the `length` and then performing a `substring()` appears to perform a lot of relatively expensive `String` manipulation for no purpose to me.

**Edit**

If you need to test starting characters only, I would prefer

```
if (str != null) {
    if (str.startsWith("red")) return "red";
    else if (str.startsWith("blue")) return "blue";
}
return "";
```

Comment: This doesn't account for inputs such as "bluexx" though.

Comment: @RogueBaneling OP's second `if` block eliminates that as a possibility. I checked first. `length` must be `3` and it must equal `"red"` or `length` is `4` and it must equal `"blue"`. :)

Answer (score 0):

regular expression solution. `^` means match start of string.

```
public static String GetColor(String input) {
    String[] colors = {"red", "blue"};
    for(String color : colors) {
        if(input.matches(String.format("^%s.*", color)))
            return color;
    }
    return "";
}
```